# Primefaces DataTable cellEditor - Update cell content

Tags: primefaces, datatable, cell, jsf-2.2

I have created a dataTable with an editable cell (component `<p:cellEditor>`), 
taking as reference the primefaces [example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml).

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{cars}" var="entity" editable="true" editMode="cell" tableStyle="width:auto">
        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{carBean.onCellEdit}" />
        <p:column headerText="Owner">
            <p:cellEditor id="ownerCell">
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{entity.owner.id}" style="width:100%">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{ownerBean.owners}" var="owner" itemLabel="#{owner.name}" itemValue="#{owner.id}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:panelGroup id="ownerOutput"><h:outputText value="#{entity.owner.name}" /></h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
```

My problem is the update of the cell. I can change the value of the selectOneMenu element but the facet component output (id="ownerOutput") is not updated. I have checked that only when the facet input and output have the same value of the attribute value, i.e.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{entity.owner.name}" style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{ownerBean.owners}" var="owner" itemLabel="#{owner.name}" itemValue="#{owner.name}" />
```

then the code works. But I want to use my original code with id.
Other solutions that I tried without success:

1. Solution 1:

   ```
   <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{carBean.onCellEdit}" update="table" />
   ```
2. Solution 2:

   ```
   public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
   Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
   if(newValue != null) {
       int alteredRow = event.getRowIndex();
       String columnName = event.getColumn().getHeaderText();
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       Account entity = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{entity}", Car.class);
       entity = service.findAndLoadEntityWithLazyReferencesById(Car.class, entity.getId());
       if(columnName.equals("Owner") {
           entity.setUsername((String) newValue);
       }
   Owner owner = service.findEntityById(Owner.class, (Long) newValue);
           entity.setOwner(owner);
   try {
           service.createOrUpdateEntity(entity);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   if(columnName.equals("Owner") {
           RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:table:" + String.valueOf(alteredRow) + ":memberCell");
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not the `update` of the components, actually they're pretty well updated.
its the `submit`.
your selectOneMenu is not submitted when you choose an option.
you need to put an ajax inside it.
a simple `<p:ajax/>` will do it.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{entity.owner.id}" style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{ownerBean.owners}" var="owner" itemLabel="#{owner.name}" itemValue="#{owner.id}" />
    <p:ajax/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```